# df.replace() in pandas 2.0.3 throws ValueError error in comparison to pandas 0.22

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace, valueerror

I used to transpose a table in a specific way using older Pandas version (0.22, py2). Recently, I had some time to start moving the whole script to Pandas 2 / py3 and I noticed it stopped working at `df.replace()`, throwing `ValueError`

Input `df` looks like this:

```
       Fruit   Vegetable  Sour_taste
Apple   1.0    NaN        1.0
Lemon   1.0    NaN        1.0
Potato  NaN    1.0        NaN
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
Apple   Fruit,Sour_taste
Lemon   Fruit,Sour_taste
Potato  Vegetable
```

I used to transform this table like this in pandas 0.22/py2:

```
df = df.apply(lambda column: column.replace(to_replace = column.loc[column > 0], value = column.name), axis = 0)

df["merged"] = df.apply(lambda row: ",".join(row.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)

df = df[["merged"]].reset_index()
```

But the first line of code in pandas2/py3 results in:

```
ValueError: Series.replace cannot use dict-like to_replace and non-None value
```

Neither I understand the error message nor why it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your code you need to mask the values, then to use the index in the `apply`:

```
df.where(df.ge(1)).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().index), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Apple     Fruit,Sour_taste
Lemon     Fruit,Sour_taste
Potato           Vegetable
dtype: object
```

Alternatively, if you have a sparse input with many rows and columns, this could be more efficient:

```
out = (df
   .where(df.ge(1)).stack().reset_index(1)['level_1']
   .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
)
```

#### what is causing the error?

in your `apply`, `column` is a Series. When a Series is passed to [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html), this is handled as a dictionary in which the Series indices are the values to replace and the values are the substitutions (e.g. `pd.Series({'A': 'B'})` would replace all `A`s by `B`s). For your original code to work you need to convert to list:

```
df.apply(lambda column: column.replace(to_replace=column.loc[column > 0].tolist(), value = column.name), axis=0)
```

Comment: I actually used

```df.mask(cond = df > 0, other = 1)``` and 
```df.apply(lambda column: column.replace(to_replace = 1.0, value=column.name), axis = 0)```

But I was even more interested why df.replace stopped accepting previous input.

Comment: @Marmach I added an explanation, but be aware that this is much less efficient that using `where`/`mask`.

Answer (score 1):

In recent version of pandas when you use a dictionary/series-like value in your case (column[column > 1]), you should not explicitly specify the replacement `value` because the replacement value is automatically picked up from the dictionary for each corresponding key. Having said that you can simplify your code to make it more efficient using dot product for reverse encoding

```
(df.ge(1) @ ( df.columns + ', ')).str[:-2]
```

---

```
Apple     Fruit, Sour_taste
Lemon     Fruit, Sour_taste
Potato            Vegetable
dtype: object
```

Comment: Just an FYI: If you still want to use your existing code the fix would be: `df = df.apply(lambda column: column.replace(to_replace=list(column.loc[column > 0]), value=column.name))`